# How can I stop cURL from outputting the contents of the page it loads into the browser?

Tags: php, curl

I currently use curl_multi_* to connect to a few sites. Its only sending a few `$_GET` variables to start a script, but it outputs the html from the sites to the browser. I want to stop this. I already use a short timeout, but sometimes the scripts start fast, and I don't want to set the timeout any lower, in case it causes it not to connect.

So how can I stop the output to the browser from cURL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true)`

This will cause `curl_exec` to return the content of the URL as a string. Not sure what the implication are when using curl_multi.

Comment: Well I'll test it out and tell you what happens with curl_multi

Comment: Tried it out. Works fine with curl_multi, assuming you add the handles to it correctly. Thanks! :D